# Filter not working in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Does anyone know how to filter in ng-repeat, the code is below. I want to filter with profile.full_name.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="job in customerjobhistoryCtrl.Jobs | filter:{customer.full_name: Profile.full_name}  ">

                            <td>{{job.category_l1}}<br/>{{job.category_l2}}</td>
     <td>{{job.customer.full_name}}</td>
     <td>{{job.customer.company_name}}</td>
     <td>{{job.created_datetime | date:'medium'}}</td>
     <td>{{job.scheduled_datetime | date:'medium'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you filter by deep (inner) object property:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in customerjobhistoryCtrl.Jobs | filter:{customer: {full_name: Profile.full_name}}  ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Should that be this, perhaps?:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in customerjobhistoryCtrl.Jobs | filter:{job.customer.full_name == Profile.full_name}">
```